# Template Class Dependency Issue

Tags: c++, templates, dependencies

I've got two classes, `DynamicCollection` and `Dictionary`. `Dictionary` inherits from `DynamicCollection` and both classes are templates. The look like this:

```
template <typename ValueType>
class DynamicCollection;

template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
class Dictionary : public DynamicCollection<KeyValuePair<KeyType, ValueType>>;
```

The issue I'm having is that `DynamicCollection` needs to have a method `GroupBy`, whose declaration looks like this:

```
template <typename Selector>
Dictionary<Selector, ICollection<ValueType>*>* GroupBy( std::function<Selector(ValueType)> evaluator );
```

So the problem I'm having is a circular dependency, and I don't know how to rewrite this so it works. I've tried forward declaring the `Dictionary` in the `DynamicCollection` header, and then defining the method in the `Dictionary` header, but then I come into this weird situation:

```
template <typename Selector>
Dictionary<Selector, ICollection<ValueType>*>* DynamicCollection::GroupBy( std::function<Selector( ValueType )> evaluator );
```

but, as you can guess, `DynamicCollection` needs a template argument list, and the `ValueType` of of the function object (as well as the `ICollection` in the return) need to be the `ValueType` from the `DynamicCollection` declaration. So, this is obviously the wrong code, but I feel like it would be something like this (if I were to have to define it in the `Dictionary` header):

```
template <typename ValueType>
template <typename Selector>
Dictionary<Selector, ICollection<ValueType>*>* DynamicCollection<ValueType>::GroupBy( std::function<Selector( ValueType )> evaluator );
```

Because when I define it like this:

```
template <typename ValueType, typename Selector>
Dictionary<Selector, ICollection<ValueType>*>* DynamicCollection<ValueType>::GroupBy( std::function<Selector( ValueType )> evaluator );
```

I get an error saying it can't find a matching declaration (which *sort of* makes sense to me).

So my question is: **how can I declare and define this method correctly**?

Comment: Did you try forward declaring the template classes as needed?

Answer (score 1):

From the language point of view, you can make that compile by declaring the `Dictionary` template before you define the `DynamicCollection` type, and then defining `Dictionary` before you define `DynamicCollection<ValueType>::GroupBy`

That being said, while you can make it compile, you still have a cyclic dependency, and that is often a *smell* on the design. There are different techniques to remove cyclic dependencies, the most common one is to split into more components and moving a part of the code to a higher/lower level.  In this particular case, you might want to consider making `GroupBy` a free function or utility outside of `DynamicCollection`, this way the dependencies would turn into:

```
    GroupBy -- free function or component
       v
   Dictionary
       v
DynamicCollection
```

Without having a complete view of the design or even the problem to solve it is hard to say whether this is the best solution, but the general approach should work regardless.

Answer (score 0):

So oddly enough, the below code solved my issue. I forward declare this `Dictionary` in the `DynamicCollection` header, and declare the method in the class as I normally would. I then define the method in the `Dictionary` header using the below declartion and things work. Two template declarations on one line. I wonder why/how this works.

```
template <typename ValueType> template <typename Selector>
Dictionary<Selector, ICollection<ValueType>*>* DynamicCollection<ValueType>::GroupBy( std::function<Selector( ValueType )> evaluator )
```